# Using python code on a local server on Mac OS X, What is the simplest way?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localserver

I've worked on a python project for GoogleAppEngine and I'm testing it locally using the GoogleAppLauncher and every thing is good till now. But lately I needed to test it on my iPad so I need to enable web sharing on my Mac book and use the local Apache server which I couldn't figure out how, so could please help me with any tutorial or any suggestions to accomplish this.
And to clarify more I've the following url: http://localhost:8095/?title=XYZ which gets me some results about the given title when it gets called locally if the associated python application is run using GoogleApplicationLauncher I need to use this URL on my iPad to get me the same results by sharing the web on my Mac book.

Sorry for the poor description, but I couldn't make more clear.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I access a web app running on my Mac via my iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534710/why-cant-i-access-a-web-app-running-on-my-mac-via-my-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to `Launch Settings` of your app and insert `--address=0.0.0.0` into the `Extra Flags` field, you should then be able to access the app from your iPad (`0.0.0.0` stands for "any interface"). Just make sure that that your firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: Might also need to forward port 8095 to your Macbook, assuming you're living behind a router.

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you accessing the app from the the devices local ip address?
something like:
http://192.168.0.3:8095